# I'm not able to view the instances of OWL class

Tags: python, sqlite, owl, ontology

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("https://test.org/onto.owl")
with onto:
    class Drug(Thing):
        pass

my_drug1 = Drug("my_drug1")
my_drug2 = Drug("my_drug2")
my_drug3 = Drug("my_drug3")
my_drug4 = Drug("my_drug4")
    
for i in Drug.instances(): 
    print(i)
```

But after creating the instances for Drug, when I'm trying to print all the available instances under Drug by using the for loop in the above snippet, I'm getting this error.

`sqlite3.OperationalError: circular reference: prelim1_objs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of this problem. Some versions of SQLite3 have a bug in the support of recursive queries. Version 3.33 is affected, while version 3.36 is not.

I added a workaround in the development version of Owlready (on BitBucket). I will make a new release soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem. Can you give me the version number of Python, Owlready and SQLite3? You can obtain them as follows in Python:

```
import sys, owlready2, sqlite3
print("Python", sys.version)
print("Owlready2", owlready2.VERSION)
print("SQLite3", sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

Jiba

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I downgraded the owl ready package to .33 and it worked for me. I think 0.34 has some bug that needs to be fixed